# JavaScript Getting Data From html get request

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON data and write it on screen. But couldn't find a way to do it. (The data that I'm trying to get are id=8 and id=9)

```
        window.onload = function() {
            loaddata();
        };
        function loaddata(){
                var url = "https://xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx.php";
                $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                    var val= data;
                  var humid=(data['relays'][(Object.keys(data['id=8'])]['status']);
                   var temper=(data['relays'][(Object.keys(data['id=9']]['status']);

                   document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = "<img src = 'temperature.png' height=\"60px\" width=\"60px\" style='vertical-align: middle' />  " +temper;
                   document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = "<img src = 'humidity.png' height=\"60px\" width=\"60px\" style='vertical-align: middle' />  "+humid;
                    console.log(data['weather'][(Object.keys(data['weather']).length)-1]['temp']);
                });
            
        }
        window.setInterval(function(){
        loaddata();
            }, 5000);
    
    </script>
```

Json Output From Url:

```
{"relays":[{"id":"1","status":"on"},{"id":"2","status":"off"},{"id":"3","status":"off"},{"id":"4","status":"off"},{"id":"5","status":"off"},{"id":"6","status":"off"},{"id":"7","status":"on"},{"id":"8","status":"61.00"},{"id":"9","status":"23.00"}],"success":1}
```

Html Code:

```
<div class="mydiv" style = 'font-family: Helvetica;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;' id="temperature">
                <img src = 'temperature.png' height="60px" width="60px" style='vertical-align: middle' /> 00.00 &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="mydiv" width="100px"style = 'font-family: Helvetica;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;' id="humidity">
                <img src = 'humidity.png' height="60px" width="60px" style='vertical-align: middle' /> 00.00 
            </div>
```

Comment: Your code has some syntactical errors: You need some closing brackets I suppose:  var humid=(data['relays'][(Object.keys(data['id=8'])`)`]['status']);
 var temper=(data['relays'][(Object.keys(data['id=9']`))`]['status']);

Comment: Thank you for your time. I made the correction but it didn't work.